# Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined - ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm trying to return a partialview after I deleted an element but it is happening the following error:

My partialview opens in a jquery modal

Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

My Action:

```
      public ActionResult ExcluirContato(int idContato, int idClienteFornecedor)
    {
        string param = idContato + ";" + idClienteFornecedor;
        int id = idClienteFornecedor;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UrlAPI"]);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var url = "api/clienteFornecedor/DeleteContato/" + param;

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.DeleteAsync(url).Result;

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Erro", "Ocorreu um erro ao excluir o Contato.");
        }

        url = "api/clienteFornecedor/GetClienteFornecedor/" + id;
        HttpResponseMessage resposta = client.GetAsync(url).Result;

        var clienteFornecedor = resposta.Content.ReadAsAsync<ClienteFornecedor>().Result;

        if (clienteFornecedor == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("ClienteFornecedor", "Ocorreu um erro ao buscar o Cliente ou Fornecedor.");

        }

        // busco os contatos do clientefornecedor
        url = "api/clienteFornecedor/GetClienteFornecedorByContato/" + id.ToString();
        resposta = client.GetAsync(url).Result;

        if (!resposta.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Erro", "Ocorreu um erro ao buscar o Contato.");
        }
        else
        {
            var contatos = resposta.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Contato>>().Result;
            Session["Contatos"] = contatos;
        }

        CarregarCombos();
        return PartialView("_CadastroClienteFornecedor", clienteFornecedor);
    }
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
   <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="~/Images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE">
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Comment: Not enough information.   How are you rendering the partial view?  AJAX?  Where does the partial view get rendered, what full view is rendering the Partial view, can we see the cshtml of the full view?

Comment: look at the source and make sure that your jquery reference is before the partial view code.  this error tells me that it is after